# Examples of locally profinite groups with compact, open and normal subgroups

Tags: group-theory, topological-groups, normal-subgroups, profinite-groups

As in the title, I am looking for examples of locally profinite groups (i.e. locally compact, totally disconnected groups) such that every neighbourhood of identity contains a compact, open and *normal* subgroup - for convenience let's call it property *P*. Such a property is true for profinite groups (i.e. compact and totally disconnected), so I am looking for other examples. In fact, the further from compactness the better.

I learnt that a theorem of Dantzig asserts that any locally profinite group has the property that every neighbourhood of identity contains a compact, open subgroup. However, there is no guarantee that it will be normal, which I care about.

So my question is, are there many non-compact examples of locally profinite groups with property *P* (if any)? Ideally, I'd love to see an example of a non-$\sigma$-compact, locally profinite group with property *P*. Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: This is called "pro-discrete" locally compact group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trivial examples of pro-discrete locally compact groups are direct products $K\times D$ with $K$ profinite and $D$ discrete. Thus you can get it non-compact, and non-$\sigma$-compact if you like. Some (not all) semidirect products $K\rtimes D$ work as well.